# Different type of users with FOSuserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm a beginner with Symfony and with FOSUserBundle. I succeeded to install FOSUserBundle and created a user that inherits from FOSUser. But now I have other types of users that I want them to have their own attributes. That means that I want them to have their own classes and tables in the DB. Should I inherit from FOSUser again or should I inherit from my existing user? I have no idea where I should start from. Any help please?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/PUGX/PUGXMultiUserBundle

Comment: I tried to implement it but it only support FOSUser dev-master. Is there any other way without using bundles?

Comment: It supports dev-master, 2.0, 1.4, etc.. if you read the section about branches  (This branch (master) supports x. The branch (2.0)...), note down the branch you require and then select it in the branch/tags drop down towards the top of the page (above the directory listing, next to the green "new pull request" button) you will be taken to the branch with the code that you would require.